# Center of gravity offset for accelerometer and gyroscope readings

Tags: dynamics, sensors, robotics, acceleration

I am working on a 6DOF IMU that contains a 3 Axis Accelerometer and a 3 Axis Gyroscope.
I am building a project to plot the postion and orientation of the turret/cabin in a crane in 3D space.
The IMU will be placed in the rear end of the cabin which is away from the center of gravity of the vehicle.
The turret can move independently from the hull/body of the crane.
The crane performs extreme maneuvers I am trying to plot those on a 3d graph both position and orientation.
I have some questions regarding this

1. Will the gyroscope have errors or uncertainty in its reading as it is placed away from COG? If yes how do I compensate that.
2. I referred the bellow article stating effect on accelerometer if IMU is placed away from COG. From this article I came to the conclusion that I have to compensate the accelerometer readings if Accelerometer is not placed at center of gravity of the body, Is my conclusion correct ?
   Can someone help me understanding.
   https://www.nxp.com/company/blog/accelerometer-placement-where-and-why:BL-ACCELEROMETER-PLACEMENT
3. If the turret is facing backwards and crane is moving forward will this change my calculations.

Comment: 1 yes - you will calculate an offset.2 what does the article not mention? 3 if you assume "foward" is positive in sign, then reverse will be negative...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I can't figure out how to calculate offset for accelerometer and gyroscope readings, is there some reference which I can refer to and work on this?
Kindly guide me since I am new to Inertial navigation Systems. I will be using dead reckoning to find position and orientation, Kindly guide me as I am new to all this.

Comment: **2** "have to compensate the accelerometer readings if Accelerometer is not placed at center of gravity of the body". You conclusion is correct; except that *centre of gravity* *might* have to be replaced by *point of rotation* of the crane in your case.

Comment: in 1. what do you mean  by "errors or uncertainty"? Also in 3. what are your calculations?

Comment: Hi solar mike, thank you for your answer, In the above post as mentioned,
Ar’ = A + Ar +  <– Inertial Acceleration 
               2ω X Vr + <– Coriolis Acceleration 
              α X r + <– Euler Acceleration 
      ω X (ω X r)) <– Centripetal Acceleration
It is mentioned that "Point P represents the location of our accelerometer within the same device.  Point Of is essentially the centre of the earth. Since points P and Or are fixed relative to one another (they are part of the same rigid body), Ar and Vr  are zero by definition and drop out of the equation" so according to this

Comment: If the position of centre of gravity and the position of IMU is fixed in a rigid body that means that the final formula becomes
Ar’ = A+ α X r + ω X (ω X r)) ------> Since in my device the position of centre of gravity and position of IMU are fixed, so will this formula work for offsetting IMU accelerometer offset due to its placement away from COG of body is this correct?

Comment: Also I found out a response regarding a similar question asked here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222947/calculating-acceleration-offset-by-center-of-gravity-c-g
Actually I need a basic clarification in this instead of  α X r here they are using cross product of ω(dot) is it correct to assume ω(dot) = α, which denotes the differentiation of angular velocity with time which give angular acceleration

Comment: Hi NMech firstly thank you for your reply, by errors or uncertainty I mean to say is gyroscope affected by translational motion of body if it is not placed in centre of rotation of body i.e, away from the centre of rotation. 
I have read that gyroscope output does not differ due to it's position of placement inside a rigid body. But I am not sure if the body is in motion (rotational + translational) is the gyroscope output affected by translational motion and if so, how do I compensate that.